# What is the name of this floral design style?

Tags: style-identification

I am looking for the name of a certain design, but unable to figure it out with the aid of Google. I have posted it here as I am currently making a magazine.

[image: Bookmark]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE, this should be the right place, but I have no clue what style this is but I can tell you is that its from the 1940's (might be earlier)

Comment: What sort of name are you looking for? "The" name of this, as it may be of a certain artist and have a proper title? The name of this *kind* of object ("ornament" should suffice)? Or possibly the name of this *style* (which for me falls under "baroque")?

Comment: Oh, this is a screenshot from a 1920s edition of Time Magazine (my bad!). I was looking for a search term so I could identify the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style is called [**Neoclassical**](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=874&q=neoclassical%20pattern%20book&oq=neoclassical%20pattern%20book&gs_l=img.3...1230.7350.0.7509.21.9.0.12.12.0.101.463.8j1.9.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.61.img..5.16.476.PiPYURFkbZA)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Jugendstil, google images for "jugendstil ornamente":

https://www.google.com/search?q=jugendstil+ornamente

HTH